# wordpress - show bookmark links of a category by letter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am having a hard time to make WP to display links of a category, in the following way:

- A
- Apple
- Art
- B
- Boat
- Bumerang... etc

I tried the following but for some reason the query doesnt show anything

```
        $first_char = 'b';            
        $links = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT      *
        FROM        $wpdb->links
        WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->links.link_name,1,1) = %s
        ORDER BY    $wpdb->links.link_name
        ", $first_char); 

        if ($links) {

            foreach ( $links as $link ) 

            {   
                ?>
                <p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link->link_url; ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php echo $link->link_name; ?>">
                        <?php echo $link->link_name; ?>
                    </a>
                </p>
                <?php
            }

        }
```

And also how can i make this to display only of an specific category.
Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct use of `$wpdb->get_results()`. [According to the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), the second argument for get_results is one of four pre-defined constants, namely:

> - OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row objects.
> - OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be discarded).
> - ARRAY_A - result will be output as an numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
> - ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.

In other words, 'b' is not a valid value. Based on this documentation (and I'm not terribly familiar with Wordpress), it seems like OBJECT_K would be appropriate in your case. You can change `SELECT *` to `SELECT link_name,*` which, while inefficient from a db optimization/performance standpoint, will set the first column retrieved to link_name. That will automatically alphabetize them for you, if I'm reading this right. However, you could probably also drop the second argument entirely and it would work.

```
    $first_char = 'b';            
    $category_id = 3; // get only category with id 3, for example
    $links = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT      *
    FROM        $wpdb->links
    WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->links.link_name,1,1) = $first_char
    AND WHERE   $wpdb->links.link_category = $category_id
    ORDER BY    $wpdb->links.link_name
    "); 

    if ($links) {

        foreach ( $links as $link ) 

        {   
            ?>
            <p>
                <a href="<?php echo $link->link_url; ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php echo $link->link_name; ?>">
                    <?php echo $link->link_name; ?>
                </a>
            </p>
            <?php
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for that you are right... your help and your time to give me a solution is highly appreciated.
I managed to alphabetize, what I am not sure is how can i get the links of a specific category, because this query gives me all the links ?... well anyways THANKS

Comment: Have you looked into [wp_list_bookmarks()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_bookmarks)? I think it might be more what you are wanting...

Comment: yes... but i need them to be separated by letters, unless I am missing something... i couldnt make it work the way i wanted... thanks

Comment: I see. I'm no Wordpress pro but I believe the adjustment I made should work. Try the edited code above and let me know the result. :)

Comment: wow, thanks very much for taking the time to do that, but unfortunately doesn't work, I dont think there is a row link_category in the table http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png, in the id of the category if I am not mistaken is in the wp_terms, i dont know how to get to that table... any idea? is a mistery... for me because  I luck of sql skills :(

Comment: Interesting! I looked in my own local wordpress db and indeed you are right, there is no links.link_category. I saw a reference to that in the Codex, I thought. Anyway, odd. If you need the wp_terms table we'll have to do a SQL JOIN to grab the info from it properly. Give me a sec and I'll sort it.

Comment: Still researching. Clearly no easy or straightforward way to do what you're talking about doing. Can you confirm that you are basically trying to do something like "display only links in [category-id 3] that start with b", i.e. not just alphabetize but display only the ones starting with a certain letter? Why are you interested in doing this? Perhaps there's an easier solution.